# Use variable in all classes and methods Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables, global-variables

I have a bunch of different UIColors saved for my iOS app and I hate redeclaring the variables in every method and class that I want to use them in. Is there a way I can set all the colors I would want to use in one spot and be able to use them everywhere in my project?

Comment: Category on UIColor.

Comment: @CrimsonChris what does that mean/ down voter explain

Comment: I didn't down vote. There are plenty of examples out there on how to make an objc category.

Answer (score 1):

In your projects prefix.pch(under supporting file group) file create macro for color like -

```
#define     MY_COLOR                        [UIColor redColor]
```

or

```
#define     MY_COLOR                    [UIColor colorWithRed:(140.0/255.0) green:(20.0/255.0) blue:(155.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]
```

This macro will be accessible in all your classes. and use it like -

```
[Obj setBackgroundColor:MY_COLOR];
```

You don't have to make any class for this. Macros defined in .pch file are accessible in all your classes by default.

Hope it will help

Comment: can I do this with other variable to like `PFUser *currentUser = [PFuser currentUser];`?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: create Constant.h file define all variables as #define. Include this file in class where you want to use this variable. 
Option 2: create singleton type class. Declares all variables in it. Create object in class where you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those UIColors in a Constants.h file and import it in prefix.pch file, just like this.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

Comment: can I do this with other variable to like `PFUser *currentUser = [PFuser currentUser];`?

Answer (score 0):

create a class colors.h and delete colors.m

and in colors.h write

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define YellowColor = [UIColor yellowColor]
#define LightGrayColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(120.0/255.0) green:(120.0/255.0) blue:(125.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]
#define RedColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(200.0/255.0) green:(30.0/255.0) blue:(36.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]
#define BlackColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(17.0/255.0) green:(17.0/255.0) blue:(17.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]
```

And import this class where ever you want and use like  BlackColor

Comment: what type of class do i make?

Comment: can I do this with other variable to like `PFUser *currentUser = [PFuser currentUser];`?